# Objective C Receive data and save it as xml file for read it without an internet connection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, file, google-reader

I have this method to get xml file from google reader with the contens of the feeds reader.
I want to save locally the data (I'm sure that data is an xml file) how can I do???
I can store locally data to read it later without internet connection? HOw can I do? thank

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)aResponse
{
    NSLog(@"------------------------------- connectionDidReceiveResponse");
    expectedResponseLength = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[aResponse expectedContentLength]];
    URLresponse = aResponse;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{   
    NSLog(@"------------------------------- connectionDidReceiveData: %@", data);
    //float l = [responseData length];
    //[delegate GoogleReaderRequestReceiveBytes:l onTotal:[expectedResponseLength floatValue]];


    //TESTING
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"the  data %@",string);


    [self.responseData appendData:data];
}
```

EDIT **

I USE THIS CODE BUT DOESN'T WORK

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)aResponse
{
    NSLog(@"------------------------------- connectionDidReceiveResponse");
    expectedResponseLength = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[aResponse expectedContentLength]];
    URLresponse = aResponse;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{   
    NSLog(@"------------------------------- connectionDidReceiveData: %@", data);
    //float l = [responseData length];
    //[delegate GoogleReaderRequestReceiveBytes:l onTotal:[expectedResponseLength floatValue]];


    //TESTING
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"the  data %@",string);
    NSString *path=@"Library/News";
    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

    [self.responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
{
    NSLog(@"------------------------------- connectionDidSendBodyData: %d", totalBytesWritten);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)theError
{
    NSLog(@"------------------------------- connectionDidFailWithError: %@", [theError localizedDescription]);

    self.responseData = nil;
    NSString *path=@"Library/News";
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [self.responseData appendData:data];

    [delegate GoogleReaderRequestDidFailWithError:theError];
}
```

Comment: U r using wrong path. You should use app's document directory. `NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *pathToDocuments=[paths objectAtIndex:0];`.

Comment: and for save data?? NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); NSString *pathToDocuments=[paths objectAtIndex:0]; [data writeToFile:pathToDocuments atomically:YES];
is It Correct?

Comment: Yes. And dont forget to add file name using `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `writeToFile:atomically:` method to store your NSData object.

Sample:

```
[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks and How can I read this data? For example I the data is an xml file how can I read it?

Comment: Ypu are welcome. `NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];`